# xmlhttprequest has stop working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i am loading a page with xmlhttprequest it was working fine but now it is giving me only the number 4 output when i load the page it gives me only [ 4 ] output without[] i.e 4 how can i fix that

Comment: No one can tell you without you including the code.

Comment: yep i have no idea... that's like saying the internet is broken...

Comment: more like saying that the internets is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about that, perhaps it's an error code? Also, check the page that you're loading, does the *page* have any code that might cause it to return that value?

Also, have you considered using an AJAX library? Might help simplify development. Check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), and see if it might help you out.

Comment: i have used both but i want to refresh page content only with xmlhttprequest not $.ajax because $.ajax is to heavy as compare to xmlhttp............any way thanks for answering me

Answer (score 0):

> "it was working fine but now it is
>   giving me only the number 4"

This is why you need to use a good Version Control system like SVN.